# Why does Windows Powershell and Command Prompt attempt to open conda.exe from a temp folder on startup?

Tags: powershell

Whenever I open Windows Powershell I see this
[powershell error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Rd5.png). It seems to me that every time I open Powershell it attempts to run conda.exe from a TEMP folder that no longer exists on my machine. Furthermore, when I open command prompt I see [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMvV2.png), so I'm guessing it's doing the same thing there.

I've checked my user and system path variables and there is no mention of the temp path that is listed in the powershell error. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you have a PowerShell profile that's attempting to launch the conda executable. Details on where you can find these profiles can be found here: [PowerShell Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2). If any of the profile files exist, open them up in your favourite text editor and see if the call to run conda is there (if so remove that line)

Answer (score 0):

When such a thing happens, it's most likely because of your PowerShell [$Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2), that is always loaded on startup.

Check the file, see if it exists and what's inside it. If you still got issues after that, let us know.